# MONGODB AND LARAVEL 5.1. I need to get all the documents updated today, how can I do that?

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I need to get all the documents where updated_at is the same date a today or yesterday,
how can I do that?

This is my current code:

```
$yesterday = new DateTime('-1 days');
$yesterday = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
$yesterday = new MongoDate(strtotime($yesterday.'00:00:00'));

$date=CampaignLog::where('campaign_id',$id)->where('updated_at','=', $yesterday)->get(array('data'));
```

Comment: try the following code, but brings me updated_at the day today and yesterday are not those in the middle
example today is 26 and want to bring only the 26th and put this

$ start = new MongoDate (strtotime ("- 1 days")); $ MongoDate stop = new ();
$ cam CampaignLog :: = where ('campaign_id', $ id) -> where ('updated_at', '>', new DateTime ('- 1 day')) -> where ('updated_at', '<', new DateTime ('+ 1 day')) -> get ();

It brings me yesterday and today.
I get only as of today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's Eloquent supports Carbon/DateTime objects instead of MongoDate objects which will be converted internally to MongoDate objects when saved to the database. You could use this date handling package in laravel called **[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)** with your queries.

For example, if you want to query for records from `CampaignLog` data where a mongodb datetime field `updated_at` is greater that a given date, say records from yesterday, use Carbon's **[`yesterday()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/Carbon/NowAndOtherStaticHelpersTest.php)** helper method:

```
$dt = Carbon::yesterday();
$campaigns = CampaignLog::where('updated_at', '>=', $dt)->get();
```

Similarly, to do a data range query i.e. query for records between a now and yesterday, use the **`whereBetween`** method:

```
$campaigns = CampaignLog::whereBetween(
             'updated_at', array(
                 Carbon::yesterday(),
                 Carbon::now()
             )
         )->get();
```

Another approach would be to use **[Eloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#dates)** which allows you to work with Carbon/DateTime objects instead of MongoDate objects. Example inspired from the **[docs](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#dates)**:

```
<?php

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class CampaignLog extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    /**
     * Collection for Model
     *
     * @var String
     */
    protected $collection = "campaignlogs";

    /**
     * Connection for model
     *
     * @var type
     */
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $dates = array('updated_at');
}
```

Which allows you to execute queries like:

```
$campaigns = CampaignLog::where('updated_at', '>=', new DateTime('-1 day'))->get();
```

Or natively using MongoDate objects, you could try

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("yesterday"));
$stop = new MongoDate();

$campaigns = DB::collection('campaignlog')->whereBetween('updated_at', array($start, $stop))->get();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but brings me updated_at the day today and yesterday are not those in the middle
example today is 26 and want to bring only the 26th and put this

$ start = new MongoDate (strtotime ("- 1 days")); $ MongoDate stop = new ();
$ cam CampaignLog :: = where ('campaign_id', $ id) -> where ('updated_at', '>', new DateTime ('- 1 day')) -> where ('updated_at', '<', new DateTime ('+ 1 day')) -> get ();

me trae los de ayer y los de hoy.
como puedo obtener solo los de hoy?